# file transfer in asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, file-transfer

I want to **transfer files between any 2 active users on my website** and have no idea how to go about it....can it be done through sockets???? i know this would be very hard to do since there has to be a connection between the reciever and the sender for data to be sent...and browsers do have privileges that windows applications have.

i am coding in vb.net....

what would be a better way to do it? any ideas or something which would point me in the right direction

thanks to all

Comment: thanks guys......figured as much that this was the only solution possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have one person upload the file to the server, and then have the other one download it.  It would be the simplest solution to get working.  After that you can start working on making it possible to start downloading the file, as the other person is uploading it.

Comment: any pointers on how to make the other person downloading it as the user is uploading it..

Comment: I believe that you need to create a httpmodule so that you can access the file as it is uploaded (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx).  Once you have access to the file stream you could start reading the file at the other end and push it out to the downloader.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in a web site without installing software on user's computer is *luckily* impossible. You could instead offer the first user to upload the file to your site where the second user can download it.